# Diccionario en diccionarios

Tags: python

Tengo un diccionario que a su vez contiene diccionarios algo tal que así:

```
variable={'query': {'query_string': {'query': 'E.keyword: {sustituir_0}'}}}
```

La idea es crear una función que va obteniendo las claves de cada diccionario y las devuelva en un array, para posteriormente cambiar {sustituir_0} por la palabra que se desee.

La función utilizada es recursiva y es esta

```
def funcion_recursiva(diccionario,resultados=None): 
    if resultados is None: 
        resultados = [] 
    if (type(diccionario)==str): 
        return resultados 
    elif (type(diccionario)==dict):
        clave=diccionario.keys()[0] 
        resultados.append(clave) 
    return funcion_recursiva(diccionario[clave],resultados)
```

Aplicamos la función a nuestra variable

```
resul = funcion_recursiva(variable)
```

e intentamos aplicar un lazo for para avanzar en el diccionario

```
z=''
for i in range(len(resul)):
    z=z+"["+resul[i]+"]"
    if(i==range(len(resul))-1):
       variable[z]=variable[z].replace('{sustituir_0}',"Madrid")
```

Aquí es donde viene mi error y mi pregunta
cuando hago variable[z] me da error y si intento concatenar tambien.

Si tengo todas las claves de los diccionarios dentro de diccionarios en una lista, ¿como se puede ir accediendo a los campos de los diccionarios usando el lazo for?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Te recomiendo que retoques tu código para que podamos visualizarlo mejor, así como te pases por la sección de cómo realizar preguntas en Stack Overflow. Nos cuesta leer tu pregunta y, cuanto mejor la hagas, mejor la podremos contestar. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes inicializar una variable `aux` con el diccionario `variable` y hacer un bucle que itere sobre las claves que tienes en la lista `resul`, excepto la última. En cada iteración sustituyes `aux` por el valor que lees de la clave correspondiente.

Al salir del bucle `aux` estaría apuntando al diccionario más interno de todos, sobre el cual ya podrías realizar la operación deseada:

```
aux = variable
for k in resul[:-1]:
  aux = aux[k]
last_key = resul[-1]
aux[last_key] = aux[last_key].replace("{sustituir_0}","Madrid")
```

Ese cambio afecta a la variable original:

```
print(variable)
```

```
{'query': {'query_string': {'query': 'E.keyword: Madrid'}}}
```

#### Actualización

Es más, te puedes ahorrar la función recursiva que crea previamente la lista de etiquetas, y usar el truco de `aux` para ir entrando por el diccionario hasta llegar al nivel en el que los valores almacenados sean cadenas:

```
aux = variable
while type(list(aux.values())[0]) == dict:
  aux = list(aux.values())[0]
```

Al salir de este bucle tienes `aux` como en el caso anterior, apuntando al diccionario más interno.

(**Nota** he puesto `list(aux.values())` para que funcione también bajo Python3, pues en esta versión `dict.values()` no retorna una lista, sino un iterador, y no sería posible entonces acceder a su elemento `[0]`)